# How to change upload dir for custom plugin?

Tags: plugins

I like to change the media upload directory for my custom plugin. Now i am testing with this in functions.php

```
 function custom_upload_directory( $args ) {
    // Check for our plugin pages
    if (($_GET['page']=="contender_add") || ($_GET['page']=="contender_edit")){
        $args['path'] = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "uploads/test";
        $args['url']  = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "uploads/test";
        $args['basedir'] = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "uploads/test";
        $args['baseurl'] = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "uploads/test";
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_upload_directory' );
```

Also how do add my custom upload folder to the media uploader library tab?

Regards

Comment: I think it's a matter of enabling the filter only in your plugin page. What's the basic structure of it? Does the filter work? Have you checked [other posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=upload_dir)?

Comment: Just a heads up but if this is for general release you do not want to store content in a plug-in directory. If you update the plug-in you will loose it.

Comment: Not an answer, but check out: https://github.com/ocean90/media-modal-demo - would love to see a working answer to this problem though :)

Comment: StephenHarris it's a custom made plugin just for one project.
@brasofilo, you got a point: f (($_GET['page']=="contender_add") || ($_GET['page']=="contender_edit")){
doesn't seemed to work. $_GET['page'] isn't defined. I am using /wp-admin/media-upload.php in the thickbox modal window. Could this be the reaseon $_GET['page'] is doesn't work?

Comment: Another question: how can i make alter the different image sizes being stored? At the moment there are 5 different sizes and for this plugin i only need 2 image sizes?

Comment: Please, [edit] the question and add details to it. If you have another question, ask a new one. Maybe check the pages [faq] and [about]? ;)

Answer (score -1):

IN YOUR wp-config.php

```
   define('MY_', '/');
define('MY_DIR','ui'); 
define('MY_DIR_PLUGINS', 'plugins');
define('MY_DIR_CONTENT', 'resource');
define('MY_DIR_MEDIA', 'media');
define('MY_PAGE_TYPE', 'http://');

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ) define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__)  . MY_. MY_DIR);  
define('WP_HOME',MY_PAGE_TYPE.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL',WP_HOME. MY_.MY_DIR);

//URL DE CONTENIDO:
define('WP_CONTENT_URL',WP_SITEURL.MY_.MY_DIR_CONTENT);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR',realpath(ABSPATH.MY_.MY_DIR_CONTENT)); 

//CAMBAIR RUTA DE PLIGINS:
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL',WP_SITEURL.MY_.MY_DIR_PLUGINS);
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR',realpath(ABSPATH.MY_DIR_PLUGINS));

//CAMBIAR RUTA DE SUBIDA
define('UPLOADS', ''.MY_DIR_CONTENT.MY_.MY_DIR_MEDIA);   

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

And change values for this vars :

```
   define('MY_DIR','ui'); 
define('MY_DIR_PLUGINS', 'plugins');
define('MY_DIR_CONTENT', 'resource');
define('MY_DIR_MEDIA', 'media');
define('MY_PAGE_TYPE', 'http://');
```

Comment: This appears to completely overwrite the uploads folder setup, instead of adding the custom folder as a new upload destination. Also, the use of constants is very confusing.

Comment: I do not agree with your qualification, it is a personalized solution, for those who are looking for, the solution to the question, can only take

// CHANGE UP ROUTE
define ('UPLOADS', '' MY_UPLOAD_FOLDER ");